# How to get the Gravityform entry ID from current user's form submission?

Tags: users, plugin-gravity-forms

**Case:** When a user submits a (Gravity)form, the plugin automatically generates an unique entry ID for that specific form. In my case the form settings only allow user to submit the form once, and only if user is registered. When user submits the form, a page is created with the content of the form. The URL of that page is dynamically generated and based on the entry-ID (www.example.com/entry-ID).

**Question:** After user have submitted a form, and user is loged in, I want to show a link to the page that is created by the user. Not only just after submission, but every time user is logged in again. But how to get, and display, that user's entry ID on a page if that user is logged in?

I have this code on the page.php to identify the user and determine what to display:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>

<?php global $wpdb;
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$where = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'page', true, $user->ID );
$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

if ( $count >= 1 ) { ?>
// This is what user see if form is submitted, where '{entry-ID}' should be replaced by the user's entry iD 
<h2>Hey <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, thank you for submitting the form. Visit your page here: www.example.com/{entry-ID}</h2>

<?php } else { ?>
// If user have not submitted a form, user is shown the info below with the form to submit
<h2>Hey <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, Thank you for joining. To create a page please submit the form below:</h2><?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="2" name="just a form" title="false" description="false"]'); ?>

<?php } } else { ?>
// if user is not logged in, user is urged to log in to submit form
<h2><Please log in to create a page <?php do_action( 'wordpress_social_login' ); ?></h2>

<?php } ?>
```

This is the function I use to make the form (ID=2) to create a 'page':

```
add_filter("gform_post_data", "change_post_type", 10, 2);
function change_post_type($post_data, $form){
    //only change post type on form id 1
    if($form["id"] != 2)
       return $post_data;

    $post_data["post_type"] = "page";
    return $post_data;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the Gravity Forms entry ID associated with the user, or the ID of the page that their form submission creates?

Comment: I want to display the entry ID associated with the current user. The aim is to give that user (when logged in) a page title/link to his created page.

Comment: There might be an easier way.  If you're using Gravity Forms to generate pages, then *there's an ID for the new page/post* in the Entry object.  I'll add another code segment to my answer to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: See above added function code I use to make Gravityforms to create a page (instead of post) if form ID=2 is used. Maybe it is useful to find out why the function to get the entry-ID is not working?

Comment: '$current_user->entry_id' gets it back when your user is logged in - you already have '$current_user->ID'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`gform_after_submission` hook](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission)[1] to add the Entry ID (and probably the Form ID to minimize confusion if you have multiple forms) to the user's meta information using [`add_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta).

```
<?php
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'wpse96468_map_user_to_entry', 10, 2 );
// to tie it to a specific form, use the format below,
// replacing '{$form_id}' with the actual form ID
// add_action( 'gform_after_submission_{$form_id}', 'wpse96468_map_user_to_entry', 10, 2 );

function wpse96468_map_user_to_entry( $entry, $form ) {
    // get your user's ID here
    // EDITED -- this should work, 
    // if only logged-in users can submit the form
    $user_id = $entry['created_by'];
    // set the arguments for the add_user_meta() function
    $meta_key = 'gform_entry_id';
    $meta_value = $entry['id'];
    // if you want to pass both the Entry and Form IDs, you can use an array:
    // $meta_value = array( 'entry_id' => $entry['id'], 'form_id' => $form['id'] );
    $unique = true;
        // optional, but the default is false,
        // and if I understand your question, you want this to be unique
    add_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );
}
?>
```

### A better way (maybe)

If you're using GForms to create a post (or page, presumably), there appears to be an easier way:

```
<?php
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'wpse96480_map_user_to_page', 10, 2);

function wpse96480_map_user_page( $entry, $form ) {
    $user_id = $entry['created_by'];
    $meta_key = 'generated_page_id';
    $meta_value = $entry['post_id']; // see note [2] for a link
    $unique = true;
    add_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );
}
?>
```

To show a link to the generated page to the user that generated it, you can add the following to `functions.php`:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse96480_get_generated_page_for_user' );
function wpse96480_get_generated_page_for_user( $content ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $current_user;
        $current_user = get_currentuserinfo();
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;
        $meta_key = 'generated_page_id';
        $single = true;
        $page_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $single );
        if( strlen( $page_id ) > 0 && is_numeric( $page_id ) ) {
            $page_link = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $page_id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $page_id ) . '</a>';
            $content .= "Hey {$current_user->display_name}, thank you for submitting the form. View your page here: $page_link";
        } else {
            $content .= "Hey {$current_user->display_name}, please fill in the form below<br />\n";
            $content .= do_shortcode('[gravityform id="2" name="Join the movement of Gooders" title="false" description="false"]');
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
?>
```

### In response to your comments

Assuming that your page generation is done as requested in the original question (ie, `example.com/{entry-ID}`, and you just want code you can plunk into a page template file (`page.php` or similar), here's my suggestion:

Add the entry ID to the user meta information as detailed in the first code snippet -- the one that begins with `add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'wpse96468_map_user_to_entry', 10, 2 );`.  All *that* code can go in your `functions.php` file, so that it'll always be available to the Gravity Forms form.

Then add the following code sample to your page template file (`page.php` by default):

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $current_user;
        // $current_user = get_currentuserinfo();
        // seems I was clobbering the existing $current_user variable
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;
        $meta_key = 'gform_entry_id';
        $single = true;
        $entry_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $single );
        if( strlen( $entry_id ) > 0 && is_numeric( $entry_id ) ) {
            // we have an entry ID now
            ?>
            <h2>Hey <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, thank you for submitting the form. Visit your page here: www.example.com/<?php echo( $entry_id ); ?></h2>
            <?php
        } else {
            // we don't have an entry ID for this user
            ?>
            <h2>Hey <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, Thank you for joining. To create a page please submit the form below:</h2><?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="2" name="Join the movement of Gooders" title="false" description="false"]'); ?>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        // user is not logged in
        ?>
        <h2><Please log in to create a page <?php do_action( 'wordpress_social_login' ); ?></h2>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

I think that should do what you're looking for.

---

[1] Gravity Forms user documentation requires you to log in to their site.

[2] http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Entry_Object -- you're looking for `post_id` in the page.

Comment: The code is working (i.e not giving errors) but it is not working as we wished. I created a fresh user, and when logged in, the form showing (that is OK) but after submission the form is still showing (instead of the first option with the url/entry-ID). I have copy-pasted your first(top) code snipet to my functions.php and added the form ID (2) like this on the first line: add_action( 'gform_after_submission_2', 'wpse96468_map_user_to_entry', 10, 2 );

Comment: I also tried the 'Better way (maybe)' function, but that gives the same result. Looks like it is not successful in getting the entry-ID?

Comment: In the `page.php` file, add this right after the `$entry_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $single );` line:  `echo( "DEBUG: \$user_id = $user_id; \$entry_id = $entry_id<br />\n" );`  What does it print out?

Comment: It shows "DEBUG: $user_id = ; $entry_id =" on the webpage just above the <h2>Hey <?php echo $current_user->display_name ?>, Thank you for joining. To create a page please submit the form below:</h2><?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="2" name="Join the movement of Gooders" title="false" description="false"]'); ?>

Comment: I've updated the `page.php` code, after testing it on my local installation.  I've commented out the `get_currentuserinfo()` call because it looks like it was blanking the `$current_user` global variable.  Hopefully that'll do what you need.

Comment: Yes!! that did the trick. Good find and thank you very much. Is there any way to PM you for future contact? I would like to mention you in the site credits ;-)

Comment: My website's in my profile -- just click my username.  On my homepage, at the end of the About Patrick section, you'll find links to my Facebook and Twitter accounts.  On another note -- if my answer worked for you, please mark it Accepted.

Comment: Sry, de solution is not working for logged in users who have registered via Wordpress Social Login (or other social login plugins). After user have registered via social login, and submitted the form, there seems to be a problem recognizing the entry-ID for these users. When I check the pages or the users in the dashboard, there is nothing unusual compared with users registered the normal way as I tested yesterday. Today I tested several social login plugins with two social providers (twitter and facebook). Any idea how this is possible and how to find an answer for that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with social login plugins.  The first thing I'd suggest is to find out how those plugins generate users -- do they get a User ID in the same manner as a "regular" WordPress user?  If not, then my code won't work, as it assumes that the user has all the fields associated with it in the database that a normal WordPress would.  Beyond that I'm not much use.